# I brought DAO tokens via Kryptokit ..I now find out the best way is to use mist - please help

Tags: mist, wallets, tokens

I have ethereum installed. Opened terminal and mist28 running in the background.
Kryptokit wallet is open in the browser and I have it backed up.
I have looked and this seems to be possible. 
Can anyone help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please state what exactly you want to do? Move tokens to Mist?

Comment: Yes ... Exactly .. It's not that I want to sell. I want to move the DAO tokens to my mist wallet . I can easily create the wallet again in mist ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download your JSON file from ethereumwallet.com
2. Open Mist / Ethereum Wallet. Go to the top bar and select Account -> Backup -> Accounts. This will open your keystore folder.
3. Move the file you downloaded into that folder.
4. Don't forget your originally password. You will need this before interacting with your wallet in Mist (ie: sending, voting on DAO proposals, etc.)

Comment: I am stuck on point 1. If I press the down arrow button I get a new page of data ...what next ?

Comment: Use chrome please